# Return an observable after a couple of actions have been performed

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, observable

I need to perform some actions (which I don't know beforehand) and after all of them are done I would like to return a void observable for someone interested may be listening to in order to do something else once this is finished.

Sample:

Class A

```
public hook: () => void;

pubic doAndReturnObservable(): Observable<void>{
    hook();
    return Observable.of();
}

public notifyToOther(){
    classB.notify(this.doAndReturnObservable());
}
```

hook is an arrow function that is being passed to class A and will include several things that would like to be performed in a generic way

Class B

```
public notify(actionsToPerform: Observable<void>){
    actionsToPerform.subscribe(()=>{
       console.log('now all has been done! I can do something else');
    });
}
```

The thing is that I don't know what 'hook' might do, there may be several actions and they could include http calls or async processes. My doAndReturnObservable method will trigger the hook with all that needs to be done but it wont wait for it to finish before returning the observable I'm then subscribing to, so my console log is being shown before the hook is done.

Does someone has a way for achieving this kind of things? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to perform some operation after some action.. in this case, You can use subject observable logic to call some function after some action...please check http://musttoknow.com/angular-4-angular-5-communicate-two-components-using-observable-subject/.. let me know if this expected else will try for another.

Comment: when hook is done, it's done. if there are async calls in there, you have to await them inside hook. you may want to rethink your design, maybe hook should be observable?

Comment: Ok...you need to use await in this case..so that when hook() function get executed then only Observable get return..will post in detail shortly.

Comment: Are you implementing `hook` yourself or do you get it from a third party / other team? As you currently defined `hook` it's a synchronous function to calling it will block your execution and wait for it to return before executing `return Observable.of();`.

Comment: @fridoo the hook is not from third parties... is meant to trigger actions from other components that may pass them as an input to the component represented on class A

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait till the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}
```

Here promise will wait to complete Promise to resolve. Ref to https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Ineed this seems to be the solution. handling the hook as a promise. Thanks a lot!